# <div> tag is not accepting CSS

Tags: html, css

```css
.pixelUnit {
  font-size: 30px;
  margin: 1px;
  padding: 1px;
  border: 1px solid brown;
  background-color: rgb(136, 3, 3);
  color: brown;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: Cambria, Cochin, Georgia, Times, 'Times New Roman', serif;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="Basic.css">
  <title>Basic</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="pixelUnit">
    Think before you ink! - Pixels
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

For some reason the div tag with the class specified is not accepting the CSS. At first I thought the CSS file is not getting loading but any other tag that I use and specify the styling in the CSS file is showing up just fine

Comment: Your HTML (`<div class="pixelUnit">`) is not using a regular space but [NARROW NO-BREAK SPACE](https://apps.timwhitlock.info/unicode/inspect?s=%3Cdiv%E2%80%AFclass%3D%22pixelUnit%22%3E).

Comment: use it - `<div class="pixelUnit">Think before you ink! - Pixels</div>`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> ```
> <div class="pixelUnit">
> ```

You have a [non-breaking space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-breaking_space) between `div` and `class`. Replace it with a regular space.

Tools like a [markup validator](https://validator.nu/) and a [unicode decoder](https://www.babelstone.co.uk/Unicode/whatisit.html) can help you identify problems like this.

```css
.pixelUnit {
  font-size: 30px;
  margin: 1px;
  padding: 1px;
  border: 1px solid brown;
  background-color: rgb(136, 3, 3);
  color: brown;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: Cambria, Cochin, Georgia, Times, 'Times New Roman', serif;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="Basic.css">
  <title>Basic</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="pixelUnit">
    Think before you ink! - Pixels
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: OMG, I can't believe it was as simple of a fix as that. I had been scratching my head for so long at it. Thanks and yeah I'll look into the tools you suggested

Answer (score 1):

Your code is working fine. I had copied and tested on notepad++, i think your problem was with the invalid space unicode.

```css
.pixelUnit {
  font-size: 30px;
  margin: 1px;
  padding: 1px;
  border: 1px solid brown;
  background-color: rgb(136, 3, 3);
  color: brown;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: Cambria, Cochin, Georgia, Times, 'Times New Roman', serif;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="Basic.css">
    <title>Basic</title>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="pixelUnit">
        Think before you ink! - Pixels
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

[image: Screenshot in Notepad++]

Answer (score -1):

Some things I would look into:

Is `Basic.css` in the same folder as your HTML file?

I know you said the CSS file appears to be working because you can style other elements. Have you tried applying the .pixelUnit class to another element and seeing if those styles are picked-up there?

Is .pixelUnit the only class in your CSS file? If not, do you have any other styles that might override .pixelUnit further down in the CSS file? I'm thinking of styles directly applied to `div` tags.

If you inspect the element in your browser, are you able to see the styles represented in the style pane?